# Difference in calculating the order for B-Tree and B+-Tree?

Tags: data-structures, b-tree

I got this simple question

```
Calculate the order p of a B+ tree if B=512, V=9B, Pr=7B and P=6B.
```

I think the answer is

```
6p + (p - 1) * 9 < 512
```

which ignore the `Pr`

but if change the question is to calculate order p of a **B-Tree** with same values for B,Pr, P and B then, I think the answer should be

```
6p + (p - 1) * (9 + 78) < 512
```

Am I correct on this?

Answer (score 0):

Each B Tree node can have at most p tree pointers, and p-1 data pointers and p-1 search key fields values.  These must fit into a single disk block if the required B-Tree node must correspond to a disk block.

To calculate p:

```
6p+(p-1)*(9 + 7) <= 512
6p + 9p + 7p -9 – 7 <= 512
22p – 16 <= 512
22p <= 528
p <= 24
```

Although p can be a maximum of 24, we choose p = 23 because the B Tree nodes may contain additional information used to manipulate the tree, such as the number of entries **q** in the node, and a pointer to the parent, therefore before we calculate p above, the block size should be first reduced by the amount of extra space needed.